# Interstitial iAd orientation on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, user-interface, ios7

I implemented interstitial ads on iPad with iOS7 and have problem - interstitial ad shows only in landscape orientation, test content layout is wrong(next slide lies on current) and scrolling is impossible on right part of display.
Are there suggestions about that behaviour of interstitial ads?

Using automatical policy